# Coloring console output in windows

Tags: haskell, cmd, package, ghci, hackage

I was trying to find if it is possible to colour console output in windows system. I found that [Console - Ansi](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/ansi-terminal/0.5.0/doc/html/System-Console-ANSI.html) but i cant find any information about coloring output in windows prompt.

I woudl appreciate information about my problem.

Comment: That package should work just fine on Windows. Can you be more specific about what your problem is?

Comment: i cant just figure out how does it work and that is additional package isnt there any library to works with coloros in std library ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's been a while, but I *think* the correct usage is:

```
setRGB [SetColor Foreground Yellow, SetColor Background Red]
```

to set yellow writing on a red background. Also `setTitle` followed by a `String` sets the console window title.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me like this:

set the foregroundcolor to Yellow

```
    setSGR [SetColor Foreground Vivid Yellow]
```

and then reset it to normal after putting your String on the screen

```
    putStrLn "ayellowstring"
    setSGR [Reset]
```

You need

```
    import System.Console.ANSI
```

to do this

Answer (score -1):

PowerShell and the console setting will be the solution.Console only have 16 colors,but you can config any 16 colors you like(i.e. you can make gray scale console)

[this link explain how to](http://www.cnblogs.com/iiaijimaai/archive/2012/09/23/2659194.html)